# Better way to define "Date Published" field for channel field?

Tags: channel-entries, custom-fields, fields

I would like to add a field called "Date Published" to a channel field group. Naturally I selected the "Date" field type but this is useless because:

- It takes too long to navigate to past years.
- It confuses the user by placing the time into the field.

Is there a way to improve upon this?

Note: It is important that it will be easy to perform a custom channel query that shows entries that are `>= N` years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it, but maybe [DropDate](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dropdate) is what you need.

Comment: Awesome, that is much better!